# Wrong order with jQuery prepend() and JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, prepend

I have this snippet of code to display some Vimeo video links

```
var videos = [72811417, 73540737, 81953800, 75087595, 98673436, 104431470, 106263756, 106286854, 108073907, 110731224, 120420600, 120914125, 127641455, 128529706];

    $.each(videos, function(index, videoid) {
        $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + videoid + '.json?callback=?', {format: "json"}, function(data) {
            $("#blocos-portefolio").prepend('<div class="portefolio-bloco video"><a class="fancybox-vimeo" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + data[0].id +'?color=F05859&autoplay=1"><img class="thumb'+ (index+1) +'" src="' + data[0].thumbnail_large +'"><img class="video_overlay" src="imagens/video_overlay.png"><h3>' + data[0].title.replace("&"," + ").replace(/trailer|_trailer/gi, "").toUpperCase() + '</h3></a></div>');
        });

    });
```

But for some reason the display order is not always the same. It should display the items in the opposite order of the array, but sometimes it just mixes it up like 14|12|13 instead of 14|13|12.
Any idea why this is happening?
Can see the live code here: http://pedrofilipe.pt/videos.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But for some reason the display order is not always the same.

That's because ajax calls are **asynchronous**, and they don't necessarily complete in the order in which you started them.

If it's vital that you put them in order, there are a dozen different ways to do that. For instance, you could add hidden divs for them when making the request, then update the div when it completes:

```
var videos = [72811417, 73540737, 81953800, 75087595, 98673436, 104431470, 106263756, 106286854, 108073907, 110731224, 120420600, 120914125, 127641455, 128529706];

$.each(videos, function(index, videoid) {
    $('<div class="portefolio-bloco video" data-index=' + index + '></div>').hide().prependTo("#blocos-portefolio");
    $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + videoid + '.json?callback=?', {format: "json"}, function(data) {
        $("#blocos-portefolio div[data-index=" + index + "]").append('<a class="fancybox-vimeo" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + data[0].id +'?color=F05859&autoplay=1"><img class="thumb'+ (index+1) +'" src="' + data[0].thumbnail_large +'"><img class="video_overlay" src="imagens/video_overlay.png"><h3>' + data[0].title.replace("&"," + ").replace(/trailer|_trailer/gi, "").toUpperCase() + '</h3></a>').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh right! Stll a noob with ajax. Nice workaround.
Being $.getJSON() a shorthand for $.ajax() of type "json", and this one supporting the 'async: false' parameter, if I use the $.ajax one for this, will it work? Not sure because of ir being a JSONP and as far as I know, JSONP request can't be synchronous. Am I right?

Comment: @RicardoPedrosa: You're right that JSONP cannot be synchronous. But that's okay, because synchronous requests make for a poor UX anyway. :-)

Comment: I tried the code, but for some reason not all the videos are displayed.
I've made this changes but don't think they affected your solution:

- changed append() by html() as that will be the only code for each div
- changed index by (index+1), just for better knowing the number of videos

Any idea why it does not show all videos? You can check the live code on the URL on the original question.

Comment: @RicardoPedrosa: Look in the web console. :-) vimeo is throwing a lot of errors, so you never get those videos.

Comment: https://db.tt/RFweCSJw

Yep. But why this happens with this code and not with my previous "wrong order" code?

Comment: Actually this is now also happening with the old code. Probably a temporary issue with Vimeo. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

Likely because doing an AJAX request is an **asynchronous** action. So it could easily happen:

```
For loop with video id 1
get json for video 1
for loop with video id 2
get json for video 2
result json for video 2
result json for video 1
```